# how to know when no data is coming on serial port unix

Tags: unix, serial-port, embedded-linux

I'm working with 2 little machines with limited unix tools. Both are conected between each other via serial. I'm transfering binary data, so the devices are on `raw` mode. The sending machine is sending files to the other one and between there's a delay of X ms (specified as parameter). I would like to know if it's possible to measure those delays on destination machine in order to identify how many files are coming. Till now i was using `cat < /dev/ttyS5`, but this is not a option to my purpose.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Atmel USARTs have added hardware to detect a receiver timeout.  But in general, especially from userspace, you cannot accurately measure "arrival" time of characters.  Trying to measure delays between characters is a fool's errand; how do you handle the case when the "next" character never arrives?.  Besides, you're asking an XY question.  You wouldn't even need to depend on unobtainable measurements if you had a proper message protocol to identify the data in datagrams/packets and to ensure data integrity.

Comment: I still wonder why people doesnt stick to the question instead of questioning why I do the stuff how I do it instead of how they like it.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the easiest way is to write a little program which is waiting for bytes on the serial line.
Everytime a character arrives some sort of timer/timestamp is reset.
Another thread could be evaluation this timer/timestamp in a loop and increment a counter if it's larger than a defined value.

But please be aware that you might experience delays from the serial line as there's the kernel and its scheduler "in between". Furthermore you'll need appropriate locking of course!

Comment: Yes, I got the same Idea. The problem I have is how to measure the time in miliseconds. I tried with `date +%s%N` to get it in nano seconds, but my machine doesnt work with `%N`.

Comment: In C I'm using https://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday. It works pretty well for relative times!

Comment: Can't use C ...Only bash/sh, quite limited one. Probably I'll have to use `time` or `times`, dont know yet...

Comment: Why can't you use C? You have a libc installed for sure ;-)

Comment: Not sure i got libc, but i also dont want to use it, cus i have a script already working and i need to add this functionality. Using C would force me to re-writte everything :(